# Update pandas dataframe value(s) from list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Imagine that we have the following dataframe:

```
Name    ID  Phone   Email
Paul    10  000001  paul@mail.com
Sarah   20          sara@mail.com
John    30  000003  
Will    40  
Evelyn  50  000005  evelyn@mail.com
```

And also the following lists:

```
['Sarah', '20', '000002', 'sara@mail.com']
['John', '30', '000003', 'john@mail.com']
['Will', '40', '000004', 'will@mail.com']
```

Is there any pythonic pandas way to update the values that are None in the Dataframe from the lists than not having to loop and look field by field?

The result should be:

```
Name    ID  Phone   Email
Paul    10  000001  paul@mail.com
Sarah   20  000002  sara@mail.com
John    30  000003  john@mail.com
Will    40  000004  will@mail.com
Evelyn  50  000005  evelyn@mail.com
```

Thank you in advance!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create DataFrame from lists, set `Name` to index in both `DataFrame`s and use [`DataFrame.combine_first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html), for same order is converted index to column, processing and last sorting by this column:

```
L = [['Sarah', '20', '000002', 'sara@mail.com'],
['John', '30', '000003', 'john@mail.com'],
['Will', '40', '000004', 'will@mail.com']]

df1 = pd.DataFrame(L, columns=['Name','ID','Phone','Email']).set_index('Name')
print (df1)
       ID   Phone          Email
Name                            
Sarah  20  000002  sara@mail.com
John   30  000003  john@mail.com
Will   40  000004  will@mail.com
```

---

```
df = (df.reset_index()
       .set_index('Name')
       .combine_first(df1)
       .reset_index()
       .sort_values('index', ignore_index=True)
       .reindex(df.columns, axis=1))
print (df)
     Name  ID   Phone            Email
0    Paul  10  000001    paul@mail.com
1   Sarah  20  000002    sara@mail.com
2    John  30  000003    john@mail.com
3    Will  40  000004    will@mail.com
4  Evelyn  50  000005  evelyn@mail.com
```

Anoter idea is use [`DataFrame.update`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.update.html), but all values are overwitten, not only `NaN`s:

```
df = df.set_index('Name')
df.update(df1)
df = df.reset_index()
print (df)
     Name  ID   Phone            Email
0    Paul  10  000001    paul@mail.com
1   Sarah  20  000002    sara@mail.com
2    John  30  000003    john@mail.com
3    Will  40  000004    will@mail.com
4  Evelyn  50  000005  evelyn@mail.com
```